# Is this a run out?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

If a batsman hits the ball inside the ground and begins running between the wickets and now the ball is thrown back to the Fielder/Bowler/WK(FBWK)

- If the FBWK catches the ball in one hand and hits the stumps with other
  hand before the batsman gets reached, is this a run out?
- If the FBWK catches the ball in hands and hits the stumps with leg or
  any other part of his body before the batsman gets reached, is this a run out?

This scenario can occur, when the ball was thrown far away from stumps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the batsman cannot be run out in both these scenarios.

> For a batsman to be dismissed by run out, his wicket needs to be put
>   down. What this means is defined by Law 28 of the Laws of cricket. The
>   wicket is put down if the person holding the ball hit the stumps with
>   his hand or arm, and provided that the ball is held in the hand or
>   hands so used, or in the hand of the arm so used.

[Reference](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-28-the-wicket-is-down,54,AR.html) (Checkout the 5th part of **Wicket Put Down**)